# Lerna monorepo publish docker images instead of npm packages

Tags: node.js, docker, monorepo, lerna

I'm currently moving my backend from polyrepo or multirepo to a monorepo.
I've successfully moved the shared packages into the Lerna monorepo, now it's time for microservices.
My project structure is simple as that:

```
root
  services
    service_written_in_node
       Dockerfile
       package.json
    service_Written_in_something_else
       Dockerfile
  packages
     shared_package_1
         package.json
     shared_package_2
         package.json
```

So basically everything in the directory `packages` should be published to the npm, and everything in `services` dir should be published to the Docker registry.

Comment: What is the question ? You want to know how to push build images of your services to your private image registry ?

Comment: I want lerna or some other script to run docker build and push for each service changed from latest release.

Comment: I don't know much about lerna, but I think I understand it's javascript stuff. If you want any microservice to be build, try to make your CI build your image and push it to the registry. I would just forget about lerna here. Just use github / gitlab ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use functionality of `package.json` and add a `postinstall` script there.

ex.:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run docker-build-publish",
    "docker-build-publish: "docker build .... {ADD HERE SCRIPTS TO PUSHLISH}
}
```

Have this in each of your services that has a Dockerfile.

At root of repo you can use `lerna bootstrap` as your postinstall to trigger install on each service.

You can always check other pre and post scripts that can fit better you usecase: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts

Comment: But this command would run the docker-build-publish for each service at monorepo, and I would like to run it only for changed ones.

Comment: @Yurgen Lerna runs only on changed ones. So having that postinstall script inside each of service , at each package.json of each service. It will docker-build-publish only those who got changed and installed by Lerna.